# Using seaborn.pairplot()

Tags: python, data-visualization, linear-regression, seaborn

I have the following dataframe:

```
              id        date  channel_id  n_tickets country_1
1224871  1614666  2017-01-01          39          1         4
214927      9425  2017-01-01          39          1        24
983594    559205  2017-01-01          39          3        19
1263871    51367  2017-01-01          39          1        24
162460    547023  2017-01-01          39          1        24
1141341  1954267  2017-01-01          39          1         4
816493   1287489  2017-01-01          39          1        24
897853    911869  2017-01-01          37          2        24
1593219  1141881  2017-01-01          28          2         4
476974    341877  2017-01-01          28          1        24
713604   1834146  2017-01-01          39          1        24
897817    639413  2017-01-01          39          1        11
283442    264653  2017-01-01          39          1        24
```

I want to apply:

```
sns.pairplot(df_final_sortedbydate)
plt.show()
```

but I am getting error as:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: float() <= str()
```

Comment: I suppose the dates are strings in your dataframe? I guess the idea would be to convert them to some numeric format such that they can be plotted.

Comment: thanks a lot. it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already found a solution, but since no formal answer has been provided, here's my take on it:

---

It surprised me a bit that even doing something as simple as highlighting and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the dataframe you provided solved the problem using `df_final_sortedbydate = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')`:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# read data from the clipboard
df_final_sortedbydate = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')

# plot
sns.pairplot(df_final_sortedbydate)
plt.show()
```

[image]

A more general solution could be, as ImportanceOfBeingErnest mentioned, to make sure that your datatypes are of a numeric format using `astype(float)`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Assuming that your dataframe has been loaded with values of a non-numeric type
subset1 = ['channel_id',   'n_tickets', 'country_1']
df_final_sortedbydate[subset1] = df_final_sortedbydate[subset1].astype(float)

# plot
sns.pairplot(df_final_sortedbydate)
plt.show()
```